Multiple SecurityFilterChains in Spring Security
In my security configuration I want to add different kinds of security filter chains.
One is for calls to /api with OAuth2 and the other is for calls to /net with a special header value with the name X-Authorization. In this value is a secret key which is used for authorization.
Here are the interesting parts of the code.
@Configuration
@EnableWebSecurity
public class SecurityConfiguration {

  private final XAuthorizationFilter xAuthorizationFilter;

  public SecurityConfiguration(XAuthorizationFilter xAuthorizationFilter) {
    this.xAuthorizationFilter= xAuthorizationFilter;
  }

  @Bean
  @Order(1)
  public SecurityFilterChain xAuthorizationSecurityFilterChain(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {
    http
        .securityMatcher(
            "/net/**"
        )
        .addFilterAt(this.xAuthorizationFilter, AuthorizationFilter.class)
        .authorizeHttpRequests(auth -> auth //
            .requestMatchers("/net/url1").hasRole(NET)
            .requestMatchers("/net/url2").hasRole(NET)
        );
    return http.build();
  }

  @Bean
  @Order(2)
  public SecurityFilterChain oAuth2SecurityFilterChain(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {
    http
        .securityMatcher(
            "/api/**",
            "/health"
        )
        .authorizeHttpRequests(auth -> auth //
            .requestMatchers("/api/admin/**").hasRole(ADMIN)
            .requestMatchers("/api/**").hasRole(EMPLOYEE)
            .requestMatchers("/health").permitAll() //
            .anyRequest().denyAll() //
        )
        .oauth2ResourceServer(oauth2 -> oauth2 //
            .jwt(jwt -> jwt //
                .jwtAuthenticationConverter(new KeycloakJwtConverter()) //
            ) //
        ) //
        .logout(logout -> logout //
            .logoutSuccessHandler(new HttpStatusReturningLogoutSuccessHandler()) //
        );
    return http.build();
  }
}

My own filter for a specific header token looks like this:
@Component
public class XAuthorizationFilter implements Filter {

  @Value("${net.authorization}")
  private String netAuthorization;

  @Value("${net.endpoints}")
  private String[] netEndpoints;

  @Override
  public void doFilter(ServletRequest servletRequest, ServletResponse servletResponse, FilterChain filterChain)
      throws IOException, ServletException {
    HttpServletRequest request = (HttpServletRequest) servletRequest;
    HttpServletResponse response = (HttpServletResponse) servletResponse;

    if (this.isNetEndpoint(request)) {
      String header = request.getHeader("X-Authorization");

      if (header == null) {
        response.setStatus(HttpServletResponse.SC_UNAUTHORIZED);
        response.getWriter().write("Missing X-Authorization header.");
        return;
      }

      if (!this.netAuthorization.equals(header)) {
        response.setStatus(HttpServletResponse.SC_FORBIDDEN);
        response.getWriter().write("Invalid X-Authorization header.");
        return;
      }

      SimpleGrantedAuthority authority = new SimpleGrantedAuthority("ROLE_NET");
      Authentication authentication = new UsernamePasswordAuthenticationToken("xUser", null, Collections.singleton(authority));
      SecurityContextHolder.getContext().setAuthentication(authentication);
    }

    filterChain.doFilter(request, response);
  }

  private boolean isNetEndpoint(HttpServletRequest request) {
    return Arrays.stream(this.netEndpoints).anyMatch(endpoint -> endpoint.equals(request.getRequestURI()));
  }

  @Override
  public void init(FilterConfig filterConfig) {
    // no implementation needed
  }

  @Override
  public void destroy() {
    // no implementation needed
  }

}

Now I call an endpoint starting with /net (for example /net/url1), but then i receive a 401, because the Bearer token is missing. This indicates, that the oAuth2 security filter chain was used.
How can i fix this?
I tried already to find solutions on stackoverflow and there where some nice entries about missing the security matcher.
I consult the docs from spring but without success.
UPDATE
It works when upgrading the security configuration to the following code:
  @Bean
  @Order(1)
  public SecurityFilterChain xAuthorizationSecurityFilterChain(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {
    http
        .csrf(AbstractHttpConfigurer::disable)
        .securityMatcher(
            "/net/**"
        )
        .oauth2ResourceServer(AbstractHttpConfigurer::disable)
        .httpBasic(Customizer.withDefaults())
        .addFilterBefore(this.xAuthorizationFilter, UsernamePasswordAuthenticationFilter.class)
        .authorizeHttpRequests(auth -> auth         
            .requestMatchers("/net/url1").hasRole(NET)      
            .requestMatchers("/net/url2").hasRole(NET)
            .requestMatchers("/**").permitAll()
        );
    return http.build();
  }

But in the second SecurityFilterChain this is necessary:
.anyRequest().permitAll()

When not adding it the call to /net results in 401.
New question: Is it dangerous to have permitAll()?

This indicates, that the oAuth2 security filter chain was used. No, that shows that you didn't add a bearer tolen. So add it to your request.

But this is exactly the problem. The requests to /net does not have a Bearer Token. I just want that they don't need it.
/net authorization per filter and header secret
/api authorization with OAuth2

Take a look here, a breaking change with no docs https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-security/issues/11958
More info can be found here : https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-security/issues/11967
I think you're missing permitAll on /** for your first config

@ClaudioZesiger Then you have to permit it. By default all URLs are denied.

@dur
Thank you for the reply. But how can I do that?

Don't answer your question in your question. Just write an answer for your question. Also don't ask new question in a question. Just open a whole new question. However, the answer of your new question is: yes, it is dangerous. That's why Spring Security changed the defaul from permitAll to denyAll.

@Kakashi, just a side note, that change is documented here: https://docs.spring.io/spring-security/reference/5.8/migration/servlet/authorization.html#_ensure_that_all_requests_have_defined_authorization_rules as part of the migration guide from 5 to 6.

The primary issue in your original post is that XAuthorizationFilter is located too late in the filter chain to be of use. I see that in your update that you've moved it to a better place. Honestly, it seems that should be the only thing necessary, so I'd recommend attempting to remove the rest of your modifications and only keep the addFilterBefore change. If that doesn't work, please consider posting a minimal GitHub project, and I'd be happy to take a look more carefully.

Have you tried to explicitly disable oauth2ResourceServer in your first security filter-chain? My bet is that it is enabled because of Boot and application properties.
Also, I like the last filter-chain in order to act as default (have no securityMatcher to intercept all requests that were not matched by a filter-chain with higher precedence).
  @Bean
  @Order(1)
  public SecurityFilterChain xAuthorizationSecurityFilterChain(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {
    http
        .securityMatcher(
            "/net/**"
        )
        .addFilterAt(this.xAuthorizationFilter, AuthorizationFilter.class)
        .oauth2ResourceServer(oauth2 -> oauth2.disable())
        .authorizeHttpRequests(auth -> auth //
            .requestMatchers("/net/url1").hasRole(NET)
            .requestMatchers("/net/url2").hasRole(NET)
        );
    return http.build();
  }

  @Bean
  @Order(2)
  public SecurityFilterChain oAuth2SecurityFilterChain(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {
    http
        .authorizeHttpRequests(auth -> auth //
            .requestMatchers("/api/admin/**").hasRole(ADMIN)
            .requestMatchers("/api/**").hasRole(EMPLOYEE)
            .requestMatchers("/health").permitAll() //
            .anyRequest().denyAll() //
        )
        .oauth2ResourceServer(oauth2 -> oauth2 //
            .jwt(jwt -> jwt //
                .jwtAuthenticationConverter(new KeycloakJwtConverter()) //
            ) //
        ) //
        .logout(logout -> logout //
            .logoutSuccessHandler(new HttpStatusReturningLogoutSuccessHandler()) //
        );
    return http.build();
  }

As your oAuth2SecurityFilterChain requests authorization ends with .anyRequest().denyAll(), it probably does what you want as default for any unmatched request ;)

Hello @ch4mp,
Thank you for the reply. I tried to disable the oAuth2 in the first SecurityFilterChain and at the same time to enable all URLs (/**) with permitAll(). In the second SecurityFilterChain I removed the securityMatcher. The call to a /net URL responds with a 401 or 403 depending on the configuration.
